# There is an approach/mechanism that will allow partitioning by next 7 days and the remaining days, and dynamically allocate new partitions

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I'm new to partitioning and I don't understand which solution will be the most optimal.

There is an approach/mechanism that will allow partitioning by date, for example: 01.01.24, 02.01.24, 03.01.24, 04.01.24, 05.01.24, 06.01.24, 07.01.24 , other_dates. And dynamically allocate new partitions from otherdate for a new day (for example, 01.01.24 I will create a partition for 08.01.24, etc.)?

I want to partition a large table.
The system works with orders. Orders are planned for the future, and can be either single or repeated regularly.

Each order has a start_order_date, the date from which this order must be executed. Every day, the system works with orders that have start_order_date <= today and deletes those that are no longer needed.

start_order_date <= today has about 30% of orders (about 40-50 million). During the day, the old unnecessary ones are deleted, and new ones for future days are added, and the next day the next section will contain about 30% of the total number of orders, and so on.

I want to partition the table so that orders that are too early to be executed are not in the field of view of the system.

If I partition by month, then the partition of the current month will take up ~70% of the total data volume, while the next 11 months will take up about 2-3 percent each.

It seems that the most convenient option is to divide by days. But it seems that in this case the number of section will be too large, since the order planning horizon is not limited by anything.

Comment: [pg_partman](https://github.com/pgpartman/pg_partman)?

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading their documentation now